# Node 14: Import modules using an absolute path for native ES6 module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am writing an app in node `14.9.0`. I have created an ES6 module by adding `"type": "module"` to my `package.json`. I am trying to import modules for my project. I want to avoid using relative imports (because `../../` is so readable) and instead want to use an absolute import as if each module was being imported from the `index.js` file in the root of my project.

From what I gathered about how node discovers modules, omitting the `.` from the front of my import path should have made node default to looking for modules from the root of my project. However, it instead tries to look from the root of my hard drive.

```js
...
import User from '/models/user.model';
...
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\models\user.model' imported from C:\Users\User\Documents\My App\my-app\index.js
```

I am not using typescript, webpack, babel, or any other transpiler. Is it possible to get an absolute import without them?

Comment: "omitting the . from the front of my import path should have made node default to looking for modules from the root of my project.t".  No, that is not correct.  If you path starts with `/`, then it will start at the root of your drive, just like any path given to any OS function.  There is no prefix that makes it start at the root of your project.  Modules don't know about your project. They only know about themselves (they are self contained in that regard) and the current working directory (which can vary depending upon how the program was launched).

Comment: If you want to go relative to your module directory, then you will need to use `./` or  one or more `../` in your path to up one or more levels.

Comment: How would you recommend setting up absolute imports in this case?

Comment: @Nostupidquestions If you're looking to resolve them relative to your project folder, that's not an absolute import. You'd write `import User from 'models/user.model';`, and tell your module loader from what location to resolve that.

Comment: For an absolute import (which is not usually what you want), you would just put the full path even including the drive.  If you show us a directory hierarchy that shows where the target module is and where the module is that you're trying to import into, then we could help you do a relative path that would not be dependent upon where the project was installed on the drive.  Or, if you really do want absolute, we could show how to do an absolute import too, but you haven't shown us where anything is on your hard drive so we can't advise more specifically.

Comment: @Bergi How do you tell node/ the module loader the location to resolve paths?

Answer (score -1):

Because you missing `*.js` extension. Its requied for ECMA node modules (https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions). This will be work (now i am developing in node 14 without Babel):

```
import User from '/models/user.model.js';
```

and in root package.json you have to add:

```
"type": "module"
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. If I use this I get the error `Cannot find module 'C:\models\uploader.model.js'`

Comment: and have you that file in C:\models\uploader.model.js ? where do you have your package.json file with `"type": "module"`?

Comment: No, the package.json file is located in the project folder in my documents. If I import without a `.` it tries to get modules from `C:/`, which is not where they are located. The package.json file has `"type": "module"`.

Comment: You should use relative path example `../../uploader.model.js`. Relative to file where you  include that model.